# Maximum of a convex function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex. Show that $f$ has a maximum that's either $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.

I tried approaching this the following way:

Let $x \in (a,b)$. Since $f$ is convex we have

$$f(x) \leqslant f(a) + \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a).$$

Let's assume that $f(a) \leqslant f(b)$. Since $a < x < b$, we have that $0 <\frac{x-a}{b-a} < 1$.

Using this we get $$f(x) < f(a) +1(f(b)-f(a)) = f(b)$$

I'm a bit stuck here. How should i continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

If $M$ is  maximum of $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ then $f(x) \leq M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ by your argument (split into the cases $f(a) \leq f(b) $ and $f(b) \leq f(a)$). This implies that $M$ is the maximum value of $f$ on $[a,b]$.